OV5640 B-CAMS-OMV Interface with STM32H743ZI
Development Board : STM32H743ZI - Nucleo Board
Camera module adapter : B-CAMS-OMV(MB1683-CAMS-A02) 
Camera module : OV5640(MB1379-2V8-A06)
Interface protocol: DCMI
Reference file : https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32-ov5640/tree/main 
Datasheet : https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/LightImaging/OV5640_datasheet.pdf 
STM-CLK - 240 MHz
CAM-CLK - 24 MHz(Onboard oscillator refer to MB1379, SM7745HEW-24.0M)
I was trying to interface OV5640 with stm32 but not getting good image, the image is greenish and there are too many noise.
My Init function looks like this.
app_ov5640_fnStatus_t app_ov5640_Init(uint32_t resolution, uint32_t pixelFormat)        {
    app_ov5640_fnStatus_t ov5640Status = app_ov5640_FN_STATUS_BUSY;

    OV5640_IO_t IOCtx;
    uint32_t id;

    /* Configure the camera driver */
    IOCtx.Address     = app_ov5640_ADDRESS;
    IOCtx.Init        = port_i2c_Init;
    IOCtx.DeInit      = port_i2c_Deinit;
    IOCtx.ReadReg     = port_i2c_ReadReg16;
    IOCtx.WriteReg    = port_i2c_WriteReg16;
    IOCtx.GetTick     = port_i2c_GetTick;

    if (OV5640_RegisterBusIO(&gOv5640Obj, &IOCtx) != OV5640_OK)         {
        ov5640Status = app_ov5640_FN_STATUS_ERROR;
    } else if (OV5640_ReadID(&gOv5640Obj, &id) != OV5640_OK)                {
        ov5640Status = app_ov5640_FN_STATUS_ERROR;
    } else {
        if (id != OV5640_ID)        {
            ov5640Status = app_ov5640_FN_STATUS_ERROR;
        } else {
            if (OV5640_Init(&gOv5640Obj, resolution, pixelFormat) != OV5640_OK)     {
                ov5640Status = app_ov5640_FN_STATUS_ERROR;
            } else if (OV5640_GetCapabilities(&gOv5640Obj, &gOv5640Capability) != OV5640_OK)        {
                ov5640Status = app_ov5640_FN_STATUS_ERROR;
            } else if (OV5640_MirrorFlipConfig(&gOv5640Obj, OV5640_MIRROR_FLIP_NONE) != OV5640_OK)  {
                ov5640Status = app_ov5640_FN_STATUS_ERROR;
            } else {
                ov5640Status = app_ov5640_FN_STATUS_OK;
            }
        }
    }
    return ov5640Status;
}

My main function looks like this.

void HAL_DCMI_FrameEventCallback(DCMI_HandleTypeDef *hdcmi)     {
    gFrameReady = 1;   //Getting this interrupt
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_YELLOW_GPIO_Port, LED_YELLOW_Pin);
}

int main(void)  {
  app_ov5640_HardReset();
  if (app_ov5640_Init(OV5640_R160x120, OV5640_RGB565) != app_ov5640_FN_STATUS_OK)           {
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)"CAMERA INIT ERROR\r\n", strlen("CAMERA INIT ERROR\r\n"), 1000);
      Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_DCMI_Start_DMA(hcamera_dcmi, DCMI_MODE_SNAPSHOT, (uint32_t)px_buf, OV7670_WIDTH * OV7670_HEIGHT / 2);

while (1) {
 if (gFrameReady)       {
   //Stop camera
   //send data via uart
   //start camera again
 }
}
}

My image looks like this.

The color bar test looks like this.

The only thing i changed from in ov5640.h in function OV5640_SetPixelFormat, is the byte order for RGB565.
OV5640_FORMAT_CTRL00 = 0x61
It would be really appreciated if anyone can give more information regarding this, like what could be the reason for such image or which registers to change for getting a good image.
Thank you in advance
